# Hiding character as underscores in php function for hangman

Tags: php, function

I am currently trying to hide characters and change them to underscores (`"_"`).
So far, I have tried these two sets of codes and they are both outputting partial strings of the word and partial `"_"`

```
function hide($answer)
{
    $hideCount = floor((sizeof($answer)/2) + 1);
    $count = 0;
    $hidden = $answer;
    while ($count < $hideCount )
    {
        $element = sizeof($answer)-2;
        if( $hidden[$element] != '_' ){
            $hidden = str_replace($hidden[$element],'_',$hidden,$replace_count);
            $count = $count + $replace_count;
        }
    }
    return $hidden;
}
```

---

```
<?php function hide($answer){
    $_SESSION['wordLength'] = strlen($answer);
    $hidden = $answer;
    return $hidden;
}
```

Comment: Why not do a strlen on the word, `for ($I <= $strlen)` and then ajax requests per guess using the success callback to fill in the letters?